# Equivalence of definitions of upper contour sets

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics

Mas-Collel, Winston and Green's Microeconomic Theory (3rd editions) offers two definitions of the upper contour set:

1. [image]
2. [image]

How can the equivalence between the two definitions be proved?

Comment: But Def M.C.3 is not a definition of the upper contour set; rather, it's a definition of quasiconcavity of a function.

Comment: Or are you asking about the equivalence between $\{x\in A:f(x)\ge t\}$ and $\{y\in X:y\succsim x\}$?

Comment: I have updated the question. The definition of upper contour set in M.C.3 is now highlighted.

Comment: Have you given the question some thoughts? This is not a particularly difficult proof.